# Trouble Getting Component to Render in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but my component wrapped in setTimeout is not being rendered to the DOM:

```
const ContentMain = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        return {rendered: false};
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({rendered: true});
    },
    render(){
        var company = this.props.company;

        return (

            <div id="ft-content">
                {this.state.rendered && setTimeout(() => <Content company={company}/>,3000)}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet this isn't working because the `render` method needs all of its input to be consumed at the same time and it can't render other components in retrospect, there's a certain flow to React. I'd suggest to separate the timeout from `render` method anyway for logic's sake, and do it in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
const ContentMain = Component({
    getInitialState() {
        return {rendered: false};
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({rendered: true});
        }, 3000);
    },
    render(){
        if (!this.state.rendered) {
            return null;
        }

        var company = this.props.company;

        return (
            <div id="ft-content">
                <Content company={company}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Changing the state triggers the render method.

On a side note - even if your original approach worked, you'd see the component flicker for 3 seconds every time it got rendered after the initial load. Guessing you wouldn't want that :)

Comment: tried it, it doesn't work.  What happens is the table of contents paints to the screen.  Then sometime later (the 3000) it does some things to it.  So it doesn't delay the render because componentDidMount runs after render

Comment: The initial render should return nothing (since this.state.rendered is false) and 3 seconds after componentDidMount the rendered will be set to true which triggers another render that would trigger a new render. If something's not working it's probably something else... got any errors?

Comment: 1. Does it get called in the componentDidMount? 2. Does the render method run afterward?

Comment: what I see is the content is painted to the dom and yes, whatever I have in setTimeout fires after so it is working in terms of the setTimeout, I just don't see the delay in rendering...all other code in the set timeout works

Comment: crap!  my fault I forgot that if statement in the render

Comment: So all is well ? :)

Comment: Great, glad to help!